# How to change tmux keyboard hotkey to do the two things at once?

Tags: tmux

How do I accomplish

```
[press C-a q] -> [me selecting one of the pane indices] -> [C-a z (to zoom)]
```

with just first two steps?

In other words, I want to rebind `C-a q <NUMBER>` so that the at the end, the selected pane is automatically zoomed in

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution should work, put the following line in your `.tmux.conf`:

```
bind q choose-window "select-window -t '%%'; resize-pane -Z"
```

Then reload it by executing this command from the shell: `tmux source ~/.tmux.conf`

Note a couple things:

- This has been tested on latest tmux version `1.9a`. It might as well work on earlier versions (but I haven't tested).
- Selecting a window is interactive! You can either press a `<NUMBER>` to select a window or use keyboard arrows to choose window.
- Zooming feature will *toggle* zoom in the target window! So if the target window is already zoomed, it will get un-zoomed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the solution doesn't work. I wanted to switch to a pane in a window, not to another window :(

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I mixed those up.